# How to Get Frequency of a note using A440 (MIDI)

Tags: c#, midi

I am trying to write a method that returns the frequency of a note on a keyboard using A440

Basically I need to convert the equasion seen [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piano_key_frequencies) to c#

Below is my interpreptation, I'm getting the wrong outputs however, whats wrong with my interpretation of this equation?

```
public static float GetFrequency(int keyIndex)
{
    /// The following equation gives the frequency (f) of the nth key
    /// f(n) = (2 * (n - 49 / 12)) * 440 Hz
    return (2 * ((keyIndex - 49) / 12)) * 440;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Exponentiation is not multiplication, and you need to use floating-point values to avoid integer rounding:

```
return Math.Pow(2, (keyIndex - 49) / 12.0) * 440;
```

Answer (score 0):

I happened to see this old question/answer and noticed the use of 49 in relation to MIDI, so even though this is old, I thought it noteworthy ;) to add an additional answer.

The frequency 440 Hz (A4) corresponds to MIDI note number 69. So although the computation is correct, and can be used for any reference standard (not just MIDI) the reference note for MIDI should be 69. The number 49 is for piano keys (more in the OP linked wiki page).

```
System.Math.Pow(2, (noteNumber - referenceNoteNumber) / 12.0) * referenceFrequency
```

Here is a wiki reference: [Frequencies, MIDI note numbers, etc.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_pitch_notation#Table_of_note_frequencies)